# Is there a way I could reproduce the box plots using the lattice package function bwplot()

Tags: r, boxplot, lattice, bwplot

```
par(mai = c(1, 1, 1, 1), omi = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
set.seed(591)
(xx1 <- rnorm(20, mean = 3, sd = 3.6))
(xx2 <- rpois(40, lambda = 3.5))
(xx3 <- rchisq(31, df = 5, ncp = 0))
```

box plot code using the R base package.

```
box1 <- boxplot(xx1, xx2, xx3, names = c("Group-1", "Group-2", "Group-3"), cex = 0.7)
```

trying to reproduce the same box plot using lattice package of R

```
box2 <- bwplot(xx1, xx2, xx3, names = c("Group-1", "Group-2",  "Group-3"), cex = 0.7)
```

I get the error code

> In bwplot.numeric(xx1, xx2, xx3, cex = 0.7) : explicit data specification ignored

Comment: It is not an error message but a warning. It does return something in `box2` but it is not identical to `box1`.

Comment: I find it admirable that you want to learn lattice but I wonder if there aren't better uses of your time. The package has been superseded by ggplot2 and is pretty much obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider putting your data in a dataframe and use a formula as shown below:

```
bwplot(values~ind, stack(list(Group1=xx1, Group2=xx2, Group3=xx3)), cex=0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to see the codes you used to create the data frame...

Comment: @Matthew `stack(list(Group1=xx1, Group2=xx2, Group3=xx3))` is the code I used. It is right there